# Post score to facebook Runtime error

Tags: facebook, lua, coronasdk

When i try to post the score to facebook, i get this error:

Runtime error ...\main.lua:22: attempt to call global 'score' (a number value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'score'

And i don't really understand why it is not working.
The full code is:

```
local facebook = require ("facebook")
local json = require ("json")

keeping_score = true
score = 1000

keeping_score = true
local scoreText = display.newText( "Score: " .. score, 20, 20,nil, 20)
scoreText:setTextColor(255,255,255)

print("" .. score)

--Facebook function
local faceListener = function (event)
   local faceMessage = {
                name = "Name",
                link = "http://www.site.com",
                message = "I just achieved ".. score"  playing Name.... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site",
                caption = "Can you beat my score? ".. score,
                description = "Name Full description here, download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site",
                picture = "http://cdn01.androidauthority.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Google-Logo.jpg",
                actions = json.encode( { name = "Name", link = "http://www.site.com" } )
                          }
   --Checks for a login and if everything is good then it calls to post the faceMessage.
   if event.type == "session" then
      if event.phase == "login" then
          facebook.request( "me/feed", "POST", faceMessage )
      end
   end
end

local faceFunc = function ()
      facebook.login("appID", faceListener {"publish_stream"} )
end

--Button to activate the post to facebook
local facebutton = display.newRect (0, 0, 50, 50)
facebutton.x = display.contentWidth/2; facebutton.y = display.contentHeight/2
facebutton:addEventListener("tap", faceFunc)
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Is this your `main.lua`? If it is, there's something wrong going on because the line #22 doesn't have any variable named `score` in it. The line is `actions = json.encode( { name = "Name", link = "http://www.site.com" } )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message = "I just achieved ".. score .."  playing Name.... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site",

Answer (score 3):

```
message = "I just achieved ".. score"  playing Name.... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site",
```

concatenation after `score` is missed